# I have anaconda on windows 10, but I want to init it on wsl2, not install it again. How Can I?

Tags: anaconda, wsl-2

I have a problem with my anaconda. I already installed anaconda on my windows 10, after a while, I installed WSL 2.0,  now I want to add the conda to PATH. Do you know guys how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Not possible.** Conda packages are frequently platform-specific which can mean dynamically linking against system shared libraries. Packages built for Windows will not find the appropriate libraries to run correctly within a **linux-64** platform.

Rather than Anaconda, consider using a minimal **base** environment, like that provided by [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html#) or [Miniforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#miniforge). That way, you have Conda but don't install all the default Anaconda distribution packages.